# Why locations.getGoogleUpdated API respond is always 404

Tags: google-my-business-api, google-my-business, google-business-profile-api

I am trying to read what has changed in my location while I have received GOOGLE_UPDATE notification from Google Business Profile API. The documentation is found here:  [locations.getGoogleUpdated](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/accept-or-reject-updates#revfields)

The result in playground is shown in the photo:
[image: Google Playground]

The result is the same in Java:

```
String locationId="locations/"+rec.locationName.split("locations/")[1];
            String url="https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/locations/"+locationId +":googleUpdated";
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create(url))
                    .GET()
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                    .build();
            
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.println(" statusCode "+ response.statusCode());
```

And the response for all the Google_Update notifications is
statusCode 404

What is wrong in my code or request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the old API, the correct one is `[Method: locations.getGoogleUpdated][1]`

so the URL would be

```
GET https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/{name=locations/*}:getGoogleUpdated
```

and the `readMask` needs to be set